# More elegant solution for multiple bit shifts

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Let's take an array of bit-masked status bytes:

```
char status[10];
```

Now, let's say we want to pull the 3rd bit out of each status byte and put them into an int, where the LSB of the int is status[0] bit 3, next is status[1] bit 3, etc.

```
int foobits = 0;
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    foobits |= (( status[i] & 0x04 ) >> 2) << i;
}
```

My question is: is there an alternative way to accomplish this that involves only one shift?

Edit: I'm trying to use foobits to contain the bit array of status[i] bit #3s.

Comment: Why would you worry about a shift? It's a CPU instruction anyways, on most CPU's.

Comment: It can be done where the data only gets shifted once, but it's more code and it's slower.  This code is as good as it's going to get.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I was just curious if there was a better approach, as I will be doing quite a bit of this...

Comment: This question may be better suited for the [code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @rudolph9, thanks I didn't even know that space existed ><

Comment: @MooingDuck Not true ... see my answer. It's a case of factoring a constant out of a loop.

Comment: The request here is not for code review ... this is not appropriate for that site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this

```
int foobits = 0;
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    foobits |= (status[i] & 0x04) << i;
}
foobits >>= 2;
```

but why bother?

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil." -- Donald Knuth